# Eclipse Application run config to intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, intellij-idea, run-configuration

Im Currently working in an old java swing project with eclipse IDE. we wanted to change from eclipse to intellij but we have a problem configuring our eclipse application in intellij.
I have tried to generate .launch file and convert it as intellij launcher with eclipser plugin but didn't work.

I have configured maven and everything.
The only problem is that im not finding any type of configuration in Intellij as Eclipse application configuration.

Any suggestions?
[image: eclipse application configuration]

Comment: is it a maven project??

Comment: @VishwaRatna yes

Comment: You cannot do this with Intellij because Intellij does not support Eclipse applications. Maven can only be used with the Maven plug-in Tycho for that. But the dependencies are not specified in the `pom.xml` file, but in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (since it's OSGi).

Answer (score 1):

Goto **Add maven project** , then Just locate your POM.xml and add it.

This is the simplest way to add maven project to intelliJ.

[image]

To add Run configuration:

[image]

After Edit Configuration you need to add Maven there like below image:

[image]

Comment: im trying to run the application not to build it. I have configured maven successfully.

Comment: if you see the picture in eclips i have created an Eclipse application run configuration but i cant do the same in intellij

Comment: on top right side near the bug, you will see a green triangular button, near that click like image above.

Comment: @RicardKollcaku , now after clicking **Edit Configuration** , just select the files and comman like `clean` `build`  etc

Comment: yes i have tried to configure as Application but it doesn't work

Comment: go to left most + sign in Edit configuration menu, you have to add maven there., wait a sec, i will add image.

Comment: you're misunderstanding  the problem. i have configured maven successfully but the problem is im not able to run it

Comment: @RicardKollcaku , explain me what error you are getting.

Comment: i dont have any maven error. Maven is cool :D. in eclipse i have an Eclipse application configuration with product and plugins that run my application. But in intellij i dont have any

Comment: You really need to read the application configuration and add exactly match the requirement in intelli run configuration.

Comment: You too have to build the project as the target folder would not be generated while copying the project just from eclipse and pom in intellij.

Comment: the problem is that im not finding in intellij any type of configuration that i can make it as in eclipse

Comment: What i see from your partial screenshot is that you need to set the location and same here also you will be required.

Comment: Send the screenshot after after my last screenshot. I am sure there is file option there also.

Comment: location is screenshot is generated by eclipse as runtime location and is not part of my project but is in eclipse workspace

Comment: Workspace is auto generated by eclipse that save all the project configurations is not created by me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206791/discussion-between-ricard-kollcaku-and-vishwa-ratna).

Comment: Ohh..man you need to point maven to the working directory, then only it will know what work on, pom is just set of dependency management.

Comment: @VishwaRatna It's an Eclipse application, not a plain Java application. The dependencies are not specified in the `pom.xml` file. Maven can only be used with the Maven plug-in Tycho to build an Eclipse application. Eclipse is based on OSGi, with plug-ins/bundles that can be installed, started, stopped and uninstalled at runtime. A Maven repository cannot be used to resolve these OSGi dependencies. Intellij does not support Eclipse applications.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run a project in Intellij, after you created or imported the project, is to alt-click the main class or the Application class and select "run Application". Intellij will setup your run and debug configurations for you.

Comment: the problem is im using eclipse application not Application. i dont have any main class i just have some configurations when i select running product and plugins

Comment: Under "run a project" there is a class you specified. I assume the code for that class is specific for the Eclipse application plugin. You'll have to modify it to work with Intellij. Like you'll need a main class, a Spring Boot Application class, or a plugin-specific class that works witn Intellij. I would be surprised if there's a way to mimic the Eclipse Application plugin in Intellij out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i was searching for any solution with configuration as im not allowed to change the code.